# APA6 reference: Chapter in book

Tags: bibtex, apa6

I have trouble referencing a chapter in an edited book using `apa6.cls`. I use Jabref to create the `.bib` file for my references.

**What I want is:**

> Good, B., & Kleinman, A. (1985). Anxiety and the anxiety disorders. In
>   A. H. Tuma & J. D. Maser (Eds.), ***Anxiety and the Anxiety
>   Disorders*** (p. 297-323). Hillsdale, NJ, England: Lawrence Erlbaum
>   Associates, Inc

but this is what I got:

> Good, B., & Kleinman, A. (1985). Anxiety and the anxiety disorders. In
>   A. H. Tuma & J. D. Maser (Eds.), (p. 297-323). Hillsdale, NJ, England:
>   Lawrence Erlbaum Associates, Inc.

The title of the book is missing. This is the `bibtex` code I have from Jabref:

```
@INBOOK{Good1985,
  chapter = {Culture and anxiety: Cross-cultural evidence for the patterning of
    anxiety disorders Anxiety and the anxiety disorders},

  pages = {297-323},

  title = {Anxiety and the Anxiety Disorders},

  publisher = {Hillsdale, NJ, England: Lawrence Erlbaum Associates, Inc.},

  year = {1985},

  editor = {Tuma, A. H. and Maser, J. D.},

  author = {Good, B. and Kleinman, A.},

  timestamp = {2013.05.22}
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "inbook" entry, I believe you should use "incollection" entry. That should work ;)

Alain

Answer (score 0):

Using title and booktitle rather than chapter and title appears to work.